# Close a FILE pointer without closing the underlying file descriptor

Tags: c, file, stream, stdio, libc

By using `fdopen()`, `fileno()` it's possible to open streams with existing file descriptors. However the proper way to close a file, once you've opened it with a stream is to `fclose()` the `FILE` pointer. How can one close the stream, but retain the open file descriptor?

This behaviour is akin to calling `fflush()` and then `fileno()`, and then never using the `FILE` pointer again, except in closing. An additional concern is that if you then `fdopen()` again, there are now multiple `FILE` pointers, and you can only close one of them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're on a POSIXy system (which I assume you are, since you have `fileno()`), you can use [`dup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) to clone the file descriptor:

```
int newfd = dup(fileno(stream));
fclose(stream);
```

Or you can hand `fdopen()` a duplicate file descriptor:

```
FILE *stream = fdopen(dup(fd), "r");
```

Either way, the other copy of the fd won't close with the `FILE *`. However, keep in mind the location pointer *is* shared, so be careful if you are using both at the same time. Also, any `fcntl()` locks held on the original fd *will* be released when you close the copy.

Comment: windows and other platforms support fileno()!
i can't believe i didn't think of this dup() solution, very elegant, and obvious

Comment: Don't you also need to dup2() the new fd back to the original fd and then close() the new fd so everything is back the way it was before, except the file stream is closed?  :D  Which means you need oldfd = fileno(stream) before you do fclose().

Comment: Jonathan, doing do is racy in multithreaded applications. It's better to `dup` before giving the fd to `fdopen` so you can be sure it never touches your original.

Comment: @bdonlan, explain: i don't see how it's racy

Comment: Thread A: close(42); Thread B: open(...) (returns 42) Thread A: dup2(42, 54); Now thread B's fd has been closed and replaced with whatever thread A was working with.

Comment: yeah but that's unavoidable regardless of how you pass the fd around. no threads are introduced between the dup, and fdopen, you just need to make sure that no thread closes it in that time. the code as given above is in no way racy on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

If everything else fails, dup(2) could help.